# Pass a string to the crash report for custom errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fatal-error

I realised that if I call

```
fatalError("It's not flying in flight mode")
```

the crash report will strip that string leaving me with only a `SIGTRAP`.

Is there a way to throw an error with a string for the crash report without it being stripped? (note that I am talking about release build, which get compiled with `-O`, not `-Onone`)

Comment: @Paulw11 It does not seem to work, I don't see the NSException's name nor reason

Comment: I did `let exception = NSException(name: NSExceptionName(rawValue: "TEST_ERROR"), reason: "MY TEST STRING", userInfo: nil)` `exception.raise()` and all I got was `Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
`

Comment: [according to Joe Groff in 2017](https://forums.swift.org/t/intercept-fatalerror-or-other-termination-messages-from-swift/6190/10): "_iOS on-device prunes the application-specific info from crash logs because of user privacy concerns_". And I believe this also applies to macOS nowadays.